# Regarding sync issue in mobilink sever

Tags: mobilink

```
E. <52> [-10117] Stream Error: Internal error: DelayExpired: _state.http_state returned 0.
W. <52> [10088] The current SQL statement has been running for too long in the consolidated database.  The connection ID is SPID '76'
```

I am unable to sync the server db to android mobile and it gives the above error.

Comment: What is the timeout for you sync?

Comment: Timeout for the sync is 120

Answer (score 0):

By restarting SQL Server and MobiLink seems to have resolved.But it is taking too long time to sync the 10mb data.

Comment: Alter your timeout, it might be that the person has a bad connection on his client causing the mobilink not to sync

Comment: can it be server problem?? because i checked with client connection and its fine.